# Реализовать команды для CMD(bat) в Autoit

Tags: cmd, bat, autoit

Идея такая: на MikroTik сделал Port Knocking, задал все необходимые параметры. Теперь, чтобы открыть порт, нужно запустить `.bat` файл со следующими командами:

```
ping 1.2.3.4 -l 707 -n 2
ping 1.2.3.4 -l 301 -n 2
ping 1.2.3.4 -l 923 -n 2
ping 1.2.3.4 -l 734 -n 2
```

Я бы хотел это сделать в Autoit: cобрать .exe, сделать иконку и чтобы при нажатии исполнялись данные пинги, после чего запускался `mstsc.exe` и просто хотелось бы отдавать людям что бы они могли получить удалённый доступ не вдаваясь как это работает, нажал да сделалось.